# Difference in SOAP envelope from Java Client calling .NET SOAP Web-Service

Tags: java, c#, web-services, soap, axis

I have a C# client which produces the .NET SOAP envelope below, which works against a C# ASMX SOAP web service. However we have a Java Client calling into our service which is producing the Java envelope specified below. The main difference between the envelopes is that some values are serialised as attributes in the java client envelope rather than as XML element nodes in the C# client envelope. The java client is using AXIS WSDL2Java to generate their client. Would anyone know what I would need to tell the Java developers so they may generate the correct soap envelope for the example shown.

Kind Regards

**Working SOAP Envelope Captured from C# Client**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <getDocumentPageRequest xmlns="urn:mycorp-com:MyApp.Schema.DocumentEnquiry.Messages.v01">
      <header xmlns="urn:mycorp-com:MyApp.Schema.Common.Types.v01">
        <extensions />
        <corelationIdentifier>41edebfb-fffd-44f8-94e9-be043e1dad48</corelationIdentifier>
      </header>
      <securityToken xmlns="urn:mycorp-com:MyApp.Schema.Common.Types.v01">
        <Value>218FD85D</Value>
      </securityToken>
      <documentIdentifier>15236HDFG000005</documentIdentifier>
      <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
    </getDocumentPageRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Java SOAP Envelope - Not working with web-service**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <getDocumentPageRequest 
      documentIdentifier="15236HDFG000005" 
      pageNumber="1" 
      xmlns="urn:mycorp-com:MyApp.Schema.DocumentEnquiry.Messages.v01">
      <ns1:header corelationIdentifier="" xmlns:ns1="urn:mycorp-com:MyApp.Schema.Common.Types.v01">
        <ns1:extensions/>
      </ns1:header>
      <ns2:securityToken xmlns:ns2="urn:mycorp-com:MyApp.Schema.Common.Types.v01">218FD85D</ns2:securityToken>
    </getDocumentPageRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Edited:: Added in WSDL as requested.

**Sample WSDL and XSD Extract**

Below is a sample of the WSDL generated and an extract of the XSD that it imports for the message type. I can see in this that the XML has attributes, which is what the AXIS WSDL2Java is generating, but the C# proxy and web-service is expecting XML nodes. I think this means the way the C# services is implemented is different somehow or other than the schema it is defined against. This is confusing...

```
<!-- WSDL Extract -->
<message name="getDocumentPageIn">
  <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
  <part name="messagePart" element="import0:getDocumentPageRequest" />
</message>
<message name="getDocumentPageOut">
  <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
  <part name="messagePart" element="import0:getDocumentPageResponse" />
</message>
<!-- import0 XSD extract -->
<xs:element name="getDocumentPageRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="MyApp:request">
                <xs:attribute name="documentIdentifier" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="pageNumber" type="xs:short" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: How does the WSDL generated for the service look?

Comment: Thanks @noMad17, Updated question with sample of WSDL as request .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking the time to review this, but I found the actual problem.

It turns out the C# code that was being generated for the types for the web-service and proxy was missing an [XmlAttribute] attribute in the code for each attribute defined in the XML. This caused the XmlSerializer to flatten the properties on the class to elements rather than keeping them as attributes.